# Write strings to a file while downloading new one simultaneous

Tags: c#, performance, beginner, multithreading

I created this console app that gets some JSON strings from a web request using a `Parallel.For` loop,

```
class Program
{
    private static readonly object ConsoleLock = new object();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //DECLARATION
        var link = "http://www.mytestrequest.com/id="
        int start = 1000;
        int end = 2000;
        var requestDid = 0;
        var requestToDo = end - start;
        ParallelOptions parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions();
        parallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8;

        List<string> jsonResponses = new List<string>();
        var baseAddress = new Uri("http://www.mytestrequest.com");
        var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        cookieContainer.Add(baseAddress,new Cookie("JSESSIONID", "xxx"));
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler() {CookieContainer = cookieContainer};
        var client = new HttpClient(handler) {BaseAddress = baseAddress};

        //CODE START HERE
        var task = Parallel.For((long)start, (long)end, parallelOptions, async i =>
        {
            lock (ConsoleLock)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
                Console.Write($"Progress {requestDid++}/{requestToDo}     ");
            }

            jsonResponses.Add(client.GetStringAsync(link + i).Result);
        });

        while (!task.IsCompleted)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Writing to file");

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter("N:/sctest.txt"))
        {
            foreach (var sc in jsonResponses)
            {
                streamWriter.WriteLine(sc);
            }
        }
        client.Dispose();
        handler.Dispose();
    }
```

I was trying to achieve the best result performance for this purpose and I thought it was possible to **write to a file what I already got in the list while still downloading other elements** but didn't know how to achieve it, should I use `ContinueWith()`? But how?

I would also like to avoid to make too many requests at the same time, what I've noticed is that if I try to add the await to the `GetStringAsync()` it seems to make thousands of requests at same time, instead, if I wait the `Result` this seems to only move over following the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`.

Comment: We require that the code be working correctly, to the best of the author's knowledge, before proceeding with a review. Please [**follow the tour**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/tour), and read [**"What topics can I ask about here?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/on-topic), [**"How do I ask a good question?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**"What types of questions should I avoid asking?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Hi @BCdotWEB how i can make working correctly a code that has access to a session aware web page? Should i simulate request delay with Thread.sleep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of interesting things going on in your code. There are many ways to solve your problem, here is an approach utilizing an `ActionBlock`. I used .NET Core 3.1 to build the sample, but `ActionBlock` is available in the System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow NuGet Package if it isn't included in your framework by default.

1) Change your entry point from `static void Main(string[] args` to `static async Task Main(string[] args` async main has been available since C#7.1 (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-1). If you can't use C#7.1 or greater, you can still do it with something like `DoAsyncWork().GetAwaiter().GetResult()`

2) `List` is not guaranteed to be thread safe and I noticed you add to your list outside your lock. I elected to use a `ConcurrentDictionary` instead since that is guaranteed thread safe. I try to avoid my own locks whenever I can and in this case, if you get rid of the Console writes, you could dump your lock altogether.

3) I elected to use `Interlocked.Increment(ref requestDid)` instead of `{requestDid++}` and then read it with an `Interlocked.Read`. Interlocked operations are thread safe, so you would be okay to use these even if you removed `lock (ConsoleLock)` (although you are only using those variables to write to the Console anyway)

4) In an async/await world, `Thread.Sleep` is almost always wrong. You usually want to `await Task.Delay` instead. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082221/when-to-use-task-delay-when-to-use-thread-sleep

5) I didn't `Dispose` the httpclient or handler because of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705092/do-httpclient-and-httpclienthandler-have-to-be-disposed (although since the program is terminating anyway, it doesn't really matter in this case)

6) As far as the `ActionBlock` goes, there are a lot of articles out there on it, but here is an ok start https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library. Note how I set `EnsureOrdered` to false. If you don't need the items to be processed in order, I find it best to set it to false. In this case, since you are writing the file after you have retrieved ALL the results, you could simply sort the values coming out of the `ConcurrentDictionary`

I set `SingleProducerConstrained` to true, because in this case post is not being called concurrently. This allows the ActionBlock to make some optimizations. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.executiondataflowblockoptions.singleproducerconstrained?view=netcore-3.1

`MaxDegreesOfParallelism` can be a tough choice. I sometimes cringe when I see a hardcode for that in real world applications because the optimal value for this will likely vary based on what hardware or virtualization platform you are running on. However, the optimal value can be hard to come by, especially when running a container. This is a great example of how nuanced the choice can be. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/622

7) Finally, I have found when testing performance like this, to make sure you do so **WITHOUT a debugger attached**. Attached debuggers can really slow things down. I built this code in release mode and then ran it from the command line.

````
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;

namespace RequestTest
{
    static class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var startTime = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
            //DECLARATION           
            int start = 1000;
            int end = 2000;
            long requestDid = 0;
            var requestToDo = end - start;

            object ConsoleLock = new object();
            ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> jsonResponses = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();
            var baseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:5001/");
            var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            cookieContainer.Add(baseAddress, new Cookie("JSESSIONID", "xxx"));
            var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = cookieContainer };
            var client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = baseAddress };
            var actionBlock = new ActionBlock<string>(async x =>
            {
                var response = await client.GetStringAsync(new Uri(baseAddress + x));
                jsonResponses.TryAdd(x, response); //note this actually returns a bool to indictate if it was added successfully, as long as x is unqiue, I can't imagine a scenario where this would return false
                lock (ConsoleLock)
                {
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref requestDid);
                    Console.Write($"Progress {Interlocked.Read(ref requestDid)}/{requestToDo}     ");
                }

            }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8, EnsureOrdered = false, SingleProducerConstrained = true }); 

            for (var counter = start; counter<end; counter++)
            {
                actionBlock.Post("api/test?requestid="+counter.ToString());
            }
            actionBlock.Complete();
            await actionBlock.Completion;
            var endRequestTime = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine($"Executed Requests in {(endRequestTime - startTime)} ticks");
            Console.WriteLine("Writing to file");

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter("C:\\temp\\sctest.txt"))
            {
                foreach (var sc in jsonResponses.Values)
                {
                    streamWriter.WriteLine(sc);
                }
            }

            var endFileTime = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
            Console.WriteLine($"Completed File write in {(endFileTime - endRequestTime)} ticks");
        }
    }
}


```
````

Comment: Hi Nelson, thanks for your complete answer, i tried and in terms of speed it is really efficient and probably, using atomic operation, it's also safe. I want to ask one more thing, isn't there a possibility to handle when an item has been inserted into the collection and automatically write it to file? Maybe creating a sort of queue without waiting the actionblock to complete his cycle.

Comment: Yes, there are a bunch of ways to accomplish this. You would have to benchmark which approach worked best. I didn't include it in my answer because the writes to the file take a small fraction of the time compared to the requests (at least with my tests). You could link to another ActionBlock (I think) or perhaps a more elegant TPL Dataflow solution using a different type of dataflow block. I tried an example using https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels/ and it wasn't any faster than my posted solution, so I am not going to post it here.